# Unable to populate multiple DropDownList on same page using same stored procedure in asp .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, stored-procedures

I am trying to populate multiple DropDownList on same page using same stored procedure in asp .net

Following is my code:

1) Page Load Event

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack){
    fillDropDown(SearchByBrand);
    fillDropDown(SearchByBrand1);
}
```

2) fillDropDown Method

```
protected void fillDropDown(DropDownList list) {
    try
    {
        cmd = new SqlCommand("fillDropdownWithBrandName", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        list.DataSource = reader;
        list.DataTextField = "BrandName";
        list.DataValueField = "BrandID";
        list.DataBind();
        list.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select Brand--", "0"));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        errorMessage = e.StackTrace;
    }
    finally{            
        cmd.Dispose();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

3) DropdownList That I have used
   **1st DropDown**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SearchByBrand" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

2nd Dropdown list is in UpdatePanel which is further inside bootstrap modal which gets open on button Click.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="SearchByBrand1" CssClass="form-control" runat="server">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE fillDropdownWithBrandName
AS
BEGIN
SELECT BrandID,BrandName FROM Brand
END
```

Only One DropdownList Gets populated. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your code:

- In the method fillDropDown you close the connection, but you dont open it again in any other visible place
- You should dispose reader object or use it inside using statement

Comment: Yes I was opening the connection in Page_Load Event only. I reopened the connection in fillDropDown method and I am getting the desired result. Thanks !!